# Retriving the text of a GridView cell selected with a radio button

Tags: asp.net, gridview

- I have used a GRIDVIEW
- in its 1st column i used a radio button
- I want to copy the **Text of Selected
  Row(via radio button) of GridView to the Label Text**
  on clicking the button...

Label1.Text = Text of 1st cell of gridview

Label2.Text = Text of 2nd cell of gridview

Label3.Text = Text of 3rd cell of gridview

Label4.Text = Text of 4th cell of gridview

Answer (score 0):

Use gridView's SelectedIndex proprety.

```
Label1.Text = this.gridView.Rows[this.gridView.SelectedIndex].Cells[0].Text;
Label2.Text = this.gridView.Rows[this.gridView.SelectedIndex].Cells[1].Text;
Label3.Text = this.gridView.Rows[this.gridView.SelectedIndex].Cells[2].Text;
Label4.Text = this.gridView.Rows[this.gridView.SelectedIndex].Cells[3].Text;
```